# How to use Fastlane with a CMake generated XCode project with dependency on WebP?

Tags: ios, cmake, fastlane, xcodebuild, fastlane-gym

I have a project written in C++ where CMake is used to generate the build system for various platforms including iOS. The project has a dependency on [WebP](https://chromium.googlesource.com/webm/libwebp). You can find an example project on GitHub [here](https://github.com/dbotha/CMakeFastlaneWebPTest) that can be used to reproduce things & I've included the relevant source files at the end of this post for completeness.

The Xcode build system for iOS is generated using CMake as follows:

`cmake -G Xcode -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=third_party/ios-cmake/ios.toolchain.cmake -DPLATFORM=OS64 -DDEPLOYMENT_TARGET=15.0 -DENABLE_BITCODE=0 -S . -B cmake-build-release`

We can now attempt to build/archive the app using [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) with the command from within the generated `cmake-build-release` directory:

`bundle exec fastlane ios beta`

However this fails due to being unable to locate various webp object files (that based on console output it appears to have previously successfully compiled):

```bash
...

▸ Compiling buffer_dec.c
▸ Compiling alpha_dec.c
▸ Building library libwebpdsp.a

...

 ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
▸ The following build commands failed:
▸   Libtool /Users/dbotha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CMakeFastlaneWebpTest-dlwvukebfiwjqvaqiepshuxqklhh/ArchiveIntermediates/CMakeFastlaneWebpTest/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/libwebpdecoder.a normal (in target 'webpdecoder' from project 'CMakeFastlaneWebpTest')
▸ (1 failure)
▸ ❌  error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/dbotha/CLionProjects/CMakeFastlaneWebpTest/cmake-build-release/third_party/libwebp/CMakeFastlaneWebpTest.build/Release-iphoneos/webpdecode.build/Objects-normal/arm64/alpha_dec.o (No such file or directory)
▸ ❌  error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/dbotha/CLionProjects/CMakeFastlaneWebpTest/cmake-build-release/third_party/libwebp/CMakeFastlaneWebpTest.build/Release-iphoneos/webpdecode.build/Objects-normal/arm64/buffer_dec.o (No such file or directory)

...
```

Internally Fastlane attempted to build/archive the project with the following command:

`xcodebuild -scheme CMakeFastlaneWebpTest -project ./CMakeFastlaneWebpTest.xcodeproj -configuration Release -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath ./out.xcarchive archive`

Interestingly an archive can be successfully generated if I use the following `xcodebuild` command (note how `-target` flag is used instead of `-scheme`):

`xcodebuild -project CMakeFastlaneWebpTest.xcodeproj archive -target CMakeFastlaneWebpTest  -configuration Release`

After this successful attempt `bundle exec fastlane ios beta` will now also succeed as the compiled object files are where it expected them to be.

Now I'd happily workaround this issue using my `xcodebuild` + `-target` flag approach and then use the fastlane command to push to Testflight, etc. but the real project (not this toy example) takes a very long time to build so building it twice is really wasteful from a cost point of view on CI platforms.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here & how I can successfully build things in the first instance using fastlane without my own explicit call to `xcodebuild` first? Or alternatively how can I have Fastlane use the successfully built objects from my workaround so it doesn't need to rebuild the entire project from scratch?

---

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(CMakeFastlaneWebpTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(CMakeFastlaneWebpTest src/main.cpp)

# Skip building of unused webp tools which fail for me under ios:
set(WEBP_BUILD_ANIM_UTILS OFF)
set(WEBP_BUILD_CWEBP OFF)
set(WEBP_BUILD_DWEBP OFF)
set(WEBP_BUILD_GIF2WEBP OFF)
set(WEBP_BUILD_IMG2WEBP OFF)
set(WEBP_BUILD_VWEBP OFF)
set(WEBP_BUILD_WEBPINFO OFF)
set(WEBP_BUILD_WEBPMUX OFF)
set(WEBP_BUILD_EXTRAS OFF)
set(WEBP_BUILD_WEBP_JS OFF)
add_subdirectory(third_party/libwebp EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
target_link_libraries(CMakeFastlaneWebpTest PRIVATE webpdecoder webpdemux)
include_directories(SYSTEM ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/libwebp/src)

configure_file(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/fastlane/Appfile ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/fastlane/Appfile COPYONLY)
configure_file(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/fastlane/Fastfile ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/fastlane/Fastfile COPYONLY)
configure_file(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Gemfile ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Gemfile COPYONLY)
configure_file(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Gemfile.lock ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Gemfile.lock COPYONLY)

set_target_properties(CMakeFastlaneWebpTest PROPERTIES
        XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET ${DEPLOYMENT_TARGET}
        MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
        MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/iOS-Info.plist.in
        MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER com.dbotha.CMakeFastlaneWebpTest
        MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_NAME CMakeFastlaneWebpTest
        MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION "0.1"
        MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING "0.1"
        )

set_xcode_property(CMakeFastlaneWebpTest PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER "com.dbotha.CMakeFastlaneWebpTest" All)
set_xcode_property(CMakeFastlaneWebpTest CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY "iPhone Developer" All)
set_xcode_property(CMakeFastlaneWebpTest DEVELOPMENT_TEAM "GFP63373B2" All)
```

**fastlane/Appfile**

```rb
app_identifier("com.dbotha.CMakeFastlaneWebpTest") # The bundle identifier of your app
apple_id("REPLACE_ME") # Your Apple Developer Portal username

itc_team_id("REPLACE_ME") # App Store Connect Team ID
team_id("REPLACE_ME") # Developer Portal Team ID
```

**fastlane/Fastfile**

```rb
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  desc "Push a new beta build to TestFlight"
  lane :beta do
    build_app(scheme: "CMakeFastlaneWebpTest", configuration: "Release")
    upload_to_testflight
  end
end
```

**src/main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <webp/demux.h>

int main() {
    WebPAnimDecoderOptions decOptions;
    (void)decOptions;
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in this topic but according to the [documentation](https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xcodebuild/) you should provide workspace to build your scheme.

> To build an Xcode workspace, you must pass both the -workspace and
> -scheme options to define the build.  The parameters of the scheme will
> control which targets are built and how they are built, although you may
> pass other options to xcodebuild to override some parameters of the
> scheme.

Scheme controls what target will be build, and guessing by your example, since you do not provide a workspace, it gets lost in the process.

The scheme is not lost anymore if you build the target manually. Since it is already build the scheme does not have to do a thing.

My proposals:

- Option 1: Try adding workspace to `build_app` parameters in Fastfile.
- Option 2:    Don't bother with building scheme just use target in the
  `build_app` parameters in Fastfile like so: `build_app(target: "CMakeFastlaneWebpTest", configuration: "Release")`